# XLS Format in Ruby on Rails Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xls

In an RoR application, I would like the index resource to download an xls file.

Currently, I can get the file to download but it requires a link to a path I created like so

```
link_to subscribers_path(:format => :xls)
```

Ideally like the subscribers_path on it's own to add the format xls, and I don't want a view in html format with index.
My file structure

```
/subscribers
   index.html.erb
   index.xls.erb
```

and my controller code

```
def index
  @subscribers = Subscriber.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.xls #{send_data @subscribers.to_csv(col_sep: "/t")}
  end
end
```

I tried to remove html to see if it would just default to another path but it says unknownformat error.  I also tried to remove the index.html.erb file to see if would fallback to another format of the same name, but that didn't work.

Hopefully my objective is clear:  How do I use the resource index path to link with xls instead of html format?

Comment: I suggest you check if rails even supports xls out of the box, i suppose no.  Hence the unknown format error. To do what you are suggesting, it would be somehow adding xls as a supported format.  Something I haven't done.  FYI: RoR uses the mime-type in the Accept headers of the request to determine which template to render.

Comment: I got it to RENDER the output I want, but how can I make it download the output instead of render?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to clarify things: Yes, Rails does fully support XLS.

To use it just put the following line under `config/initializers/mime_types.rb`:

```
Mime::Type.register "application/xls", :xls
```

Then, as the author did it, change the format to xls and create an index.xls.erb

Now, to answer your question, there is a number of ways:

The first thing I thought of, was to just change the request format. In your controller:

```
class SubscriberController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :change_format

  def index
    @subscribers = Subscriber.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.xls #{send_data @subscribers.to_csv(col_sep: "/t")}
    end
  end

  private
    def change_format
      request.format = "xls"
    end
end
```

There should also be a dozen other ways to do this, but I would prefer this one.